# sed - is this replacement with a dot is right or should I escape it?

Tags: unix, sed

```
sed -i '' -e 's/firstdomain.com/seconddomain.com/g'
```

Should I escape the dot? if so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot is a regex metacharacter meaning "match any character", so yes you do need to escape it:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/firstdomain\.com/seconddomain.com/g'
```

Within a bracket expression, dot loses its special meaning, so you could do this:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/firstdomain[.]com/seconddomain.com/g'
```

If you don't escape it, the string "firstdomain-com" (among others) would match

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dot in the second domain, as well. ;-)

Comment: so glen it's either the first or the second?

Comment: @joadha: No. It's ok like this. The replacement part is taken literal and only special constructions to reference groups are possible, like `\1` or `&`.

Comment: @Tom, yes, take your pick.

Comment: @joadha, I didn't forget ;)

Comment: Clearly, I'm the one who forgot. No escaping that. (sad trombone)